# ms-access save query result in a string

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a query saved in the queries section. I am running the query from VBA. Is it possible to save the results of this query to a string?

Comment: What is your query returning? A record set or a single item?

Comment: You have to clarify your question: do you need headers? what separates the returned fields values? should the columns be of fixed width or not? What separates rows? Is it for display or for saving to a file?

Comment: renaud, i just need the output of the query to go directly into a string, i will then feed the string into a listbox (yes, instead of doing rowsource)

Comment: so each field data in the record will be its own selection in a list box? or the ENTIRE record will be a selection in the list box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ADO Recordset has a `GetString` method which might be useful to you.

I have a query named *qryListTables* which looks like this:

```sql
SELECT m.Name AS tbl_name
FROM MSysObjects AS m
WHERE
        (((m.Name) Not Like "msys%"
    And (m.Name) Not Like "~%")
    AND ((m.Type)=1))
ORDER BY m.Name;
```

Notice that query uses `%` instead of `*` as the wildcard character.  The reason for that choice is that ADO requires ANSI wild card characters (`%` and `_` instead of `*` and `?`).

I can use the following function to spit out a string containing the quoted names of regular tables in my database, separated by semicolons, by calling it like this:

```vb
? DemoGetString("qryListTables", True)

Public Function DemoGetString(ByVal pQueryName As String, _
    Optional ByVal AddQuotes As Boolean = False) As Variant
    '* early binding requires a reference to Microsoft ActiveX
    '* Data Objects Library
    'Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    'Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    '* use late binding; no referenced needed
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Dim varOut As Variant
    rs.Open pQueryName, CurrentProject.Connection
    If AddQuotes Then
        varOut = """" & rs.GetString(2, , , """;""") '2 = adClipString
        ' strip off last quote
        If Len(varOut & vbNullString) > 0 Then
            varOut = Left(varOut, Len(varOut) - 1)
        End If
    Else
        varOut = rs.GetString(2, , , ";") '2 = adClipString
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    DemoGetString = varOut
End Function
```

Comment: In DAO recordsets you can do the same thing by putting the output of GetRows in an array and then using Join() to convert the array to a delimited list.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked for GetString first in DAO before I realized it's only available in ADO.  But I usually prefer DAO, so I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Since so many people here on SO are using ADO, I try to make sure that the DAO version of any ADO solutions is posted (where it makes sense), since DAO is the Access-appropriate interface.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: how can DAO be "most appropriate" in this case when you have to roll your own functionality that ADO has out of the box?!

Answer (score 3):

Ok.. taking a complete shot in the dark here...

The query you are running is literally a query... think of it as its OWN table... it can be referenced as you would any other table, and can be queried against.

If you are trying to return a single string item based on a single criteria your best bet is a Dlookup:

```
Lookup = Nz(DLookup(string Field, string Table, string Criteria), "")
```

If your looking for a group of records:

```
dim tsSQL as string
stSQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field=criteria"
dim toRecordset as new ADODB.Recordset
toRecordset.open stSQL, CurrentProject.AccessConnection, int Keyset, int Lock
```

Then you can directly access the fields by:

```
If toRecordset.RecordCount > 0 then
  String = toRecordset!FieldName
End If
```

W/o more information... that about it...
Also it works in the other direction as well..

You can do:

```
toRecordset.AddNew
toRecordset!Field = Value
toRecordset.Update
```

I hope somewhere in there is an answer for you.

To get the entire query you could change up the select statement from example one to "SELECT * FROM query name" and that should pull the whole thing in.